# When to use 'of' vs. 'for' in constructions like "It is (adjective) of/for you to do X"?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions, phrase-usage

Consider the following type of sentence:

> It is kind/nice/cruel/considerate of you to do X.

I understand that the preposition used there should always be 'of,' not 'for.'

Now how would we extend that pattern to the following:

1. It is decent [**of** you or **for** you] to do X?
2. It is smart [**of** you or **for** you] to do X?

I believe that the first sentence continues the pattern above and should take 'of,' while the second might be better with 'for'?

Is there any **general rule or pattern** to apply to this type of sentence to determine which preposition to use?  For example, it seems like the adjectives which take 'of' express connotations of *gratitude* (as with *kind, nice* etc.) or *the opposite* (as with *cruel*). 'Smart,' on the other hand, which seems like it would fit better with 'for' than with 'of,' does not carry connotations of [gratitude/obligation/the inverse] on the part of the speaker towards the person described as 'you.'

PS. This question does not request for any proofreading: it is only all about the usage of 'of' and 'for' in case of the adjectives like properties or qualities of a person that is described as nice, kind, ..., and/or decent, etc. , especially of the usage of 'decent'.

Comment: *decent of*, but *smart for*, sounds most idiomatic in my opinion.  I'm not sure why! :D

Comment: Maybe it's the words that express *gratitude* ('decent,' 'kind' etc.) or *the opposite* (as for 'cruel') on the part of the speaker towards the subject ('you') that should take 'of,' while other concepts take 'for'?  'Smart' doesn't connote gratitude or its inverse, so you can say 'for' instead of 'of' there, but use 'of' for all the rest.  I don't know if there is any definite rule for this though; I'm just going by what *sounds* right and guessing at the pattern.  Nice question, +1!

Comment: What do you think of the suggested edit to your question?  If you believe it improves the post and doesn't conflict with your original intent, you can approve the edit so that it is visible to the community.  Otherwise, feel free to reject it (or the reviewers will later).

Comment: "Decent of you to do that" indicates that doing the act reflects the addressee's niceness.  In general, it describes an act that demonstrates some quality of a person.  If someone has done something smart, "it was smart of you to do that" would be fine (@QuackE.Duck).  "Smart for you to do that" implies advice: "it would be a good idea for you to do that; it would be smart for you to do that."

Comment: @phoog I believe you may have just answered the question :)  Too bad it's still closed, but if it gets reopened you should convert that comment to an answer!

Comment: @QuackE.Duck Yes, that's true. His comment deserves posting as an answer.